# how to remove a string from a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, error-handling

the first element of the list is a string and the rest are numbers. I want to perform mathematical operations between the numbers like median etc but I can't remove the first element a.k.a the string because I keep getting this error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

I tried pop, remove etc

```
with open('/Users/solidaneziri/Downloads/Data_Exercise_1.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        alter = line.split()[0]
        alter.pop()
        statistics.median(alter)

print(Alter)

Alter
28
25
28
26
22
20
25
21
21
25
24
25
26
22
26
20
27
22
22
26
23
20
22
26
24
22
20
20
19
21
19
19
33
23
21
29
21
25
26
19
23
20
25
21
```

input(alter)
output = 22.5 the median

Comment: string.replace("to_replace", "")

Comment: @DaniMesejo this would just replace a string with a empty string it still won't solve my problem

Comment: I think is better if you put examples of the input and what you actually want to do with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply skip the first line.  `next` consumes one element of the file iterator:

```py
import statistics

with open('/Users/solidaneziri/Downloads/Data_Exercise_1.txt') as infile:
    header = next(infile)
    data = [int(line.split()[0]) for line in infile]
print(statistics.median(data))
```

Output:

```
22.5
```

Comment: thank you but next gives me the first row and not the first column

Comment: @nsol Well, you haven't shown *exactly* what your input data looks like and you *wanted* to skip the first row.

Comment: well I did now.

Comment: THANKK YOUUU. This is the one that worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
import statistics
list_ = []
with open('1.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.split()[0].isdigit():
            list_.append(int(line.split()[0]))
statistics.median(list_)
```

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: In my answer i haven't pop method. I don't anderstand why you have same error

Comment: sorry I mean `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: What is your file format?

Comment: it is a text file .txt

Comment: Every number in new row? And first row is not a number?

Comment: yes I edited my post so y'all can see the files format

Comment: Is it tab-delimited?  You'd be better off using the `csv` or `pandas` modules to read the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is taking the first element of the `List` at `line.split()[0]`.

If each line is formed by a string followed by numbers, and you just want to remove the first string, it should be done like this:

```py
with open('/Users/solidaneziri/Downloads/Data_Exercise_1.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        alter = line.split()
        alter.pop(0)
        statistics.median(line)
```

Notice as well that you must introduce an index of the position of the `List` that you want to delete with `pop()`.

Comment: still get the same error with this one. Data_exercise contains many columns with a list of numbers. Alter is the first one of them

Comment: Forgot the `split()` part, it should work this way. Just as a comment, in your code "alter" is not first line, it's each line of the file that you are reading.

Comment: its the first time I am programming with python. So is alter the first column of my file or not

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the string by not including the 0 index, then convert the strings representing numbers to actual floats so that they can be used in your calculations.

```
with open('/Users/solidaneziri/Downloads/Data_Exercise_1.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        numbers = line.split()[1:]
        numbers = map(float, numbers)
        statistics.median(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test_list = ["bad", 2, 4, 6 ,1, 3] 

print ("Original list : " + str(test_list)) 
R = "bad"
while(R in test_list) : 
    test_list.remove(R) 
print ("List after removing string " + str(test_list))
```

Comment: Please include an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

my_list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
print (my_list)

## let's say i want the remove one and four

my_list.pop(3)
my_list.pop(0)
print(my_list)

#The output will be

["two", "three", "five", "six"]

Comment: Hi, how is your answer relevant to the question? I see that you tried to answer to the title, but not the post itself, which is actually a different issue. Also, consider a proper formatting (use backticks to delimit code excerpts), it will be far friendlier to read.